# Animate a scale on a circle to keep centerposition

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

How can I make a circle animate scaling but keep the centerposition of the circle in the same point. This code makes the center of the circle move down and right, seems like its bound in top and left corner by the frame.

This layer is as you can see a mask on another layer.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(400, 400, 1000, 1000));

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[shapeLayer setPath:path];
[shapeLayer setFrame:[glView frame]];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

[[glView layer] setMask:shapeLayer];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 0)];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)];
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.duration = 3;
[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A layer is scaled around its *anchor point*, which by default is the center of the layer's frame.  This is explained in [*Core Animation Programming Guide - Specifying a Layer's Geometry*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW8).

Your problem is that your circle's center is not at the same point as your layer's anchor point.

So one way to fix your problem is to move `shapeLayer.anchorPoint` to be the same as the circle's center, like this:

```
CGRect circleFrame = CGRectMake(400, 400, 1000, 1000);
CGPoint circleAnchor = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame) / CGRectGetMaxX(circleFrame),
    CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame) / CGRectGetMaxY(circleFrame));
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleFrame];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.anchorPoint = circleAnchor;
shapeLayer.frame = glView.frame;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

glView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
// and then your animation code
```

You want to set the anchor point *before* you set the frame, because setting the anchor point after setting the frame will change the frame.

Comment: I have tried with different anchorPOints but still there is no change. It always animating to the left corner.

Comment: Rob Mayoff is correct. Note how he calculates the anchor point in unit coordinate space, by dividing the middle of the frame by its max in each dimension. So the anchor point must be a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: I want to add, that in most cases you don't want to change `anchorPoint` like here. You just need to set proper frame. For example: you want create shape with path and then scale it. First create shape in rect that have origin `x:0, y:0`. Then, after you set this path to your `CAShapeLayer`, you need to layout your layer by setting frame. Set frame as you need for example, like in this question `CGRectMake(400, 400, 1000, 1000)`. Now your scaling will be from point x,y = 400 + 1000 /2 = 900

Comment: Hi Rob, can you please help me with following. Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688399/expand-in-place-animation-in-cashapelayer

Answer (score 3):

These are guesses, not able to try myself at the moment:

- Set shapeLayer's frame to glView's `bounds`, not `frame` as it should be in the coordinate system of the view it belongs to, not the superview.
- Set shapeLayer's `anchorPoint` to 0.5,0.5 - this is the default for a CALayer (meaning the centre of the layer) but from what you are describing this is not the case for your shape layer - unless the frame/bounds thing is causing the issue.